# What is best way to inject configured options instance into a scoped service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

I have a service class (DynamicsConnector) which depends on another options class (DynamicsConnectorOptions). Following dependency injection I need to inject (DynamicsConnectorOptions) into (DynamicsConnector).

after hours of searching I have found one way to do it as in below code:

```
    //Code snippet for target dependency injection classes
    public class DynamicsConnector : IDynamicsConnector
    {
        DynamicsConnectorOptions options { get; set; }
        public DynamicsConnector(DynamicsConnectorOptions options)
        {
           this.options = options;
        }
    }        

    //Code snippet for configuring and registering classes
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddOptions();

        var settings = Configuration.GetSection("DynamicsConnector");
        services.Configure<DynamicsConnectorOptions>(settings);

        DynamicsConnectorOptions options = new DynamicsConnectorOptions();
        settings.Bind(options);
        services.AddScoped(x => options);
        services.AddScoped<IDynamicsConnector, DynamicsConnector>();
    }
```

This code works just fine. However, I have the following questions:

1. from a design perspective, is it a good idea to let an option class depends directly on another service class?
2. if yes, is it a good practice to do it this way, or there is more robust and elegant way to inject options class into another service class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be following the [options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2):

```
public class DynamicsConnector : IDynamicsConnector
{
    private readonly IOptions<DynamicsConnectorOptions> options { get; set; }
    public DynamicsConnector(IOptions<DynamicsConnectorOptions> options)
    {
       this.options = options;
    }
}
```

Then, all you need in `ConfigureServices` is:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    var settings = Configuration.GetSection("DynamicsConnector");
    services.Configure<DynamicsConnectorOptions>(settings);
    services.AddScoped<IDynamicsConnector, DynamicsConnector>();
}
```

You can also choose to use other interfaces like `IOptionsSnapshot`, which refreshes the options per scope (assuming it's from a config provider that supports reload, like JSON).

Comment: You can prettify this by renaming the section in the configuration and using the line below:

services.Configure<DynamicsConnectorOptions>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(DynamicsConnectorOptions)));

I personally would not prefer to hardcode these section names but to link it to the class name.

Answer (score 1):

This line of code is anti-pattern with leaky abstraction:

```
   DynamicsConnectorOptions options = new DynamicsConnectorOptions();
```

You have your container creating instances and now inline code creating instances. You mapped your appsettings.json correctly with Configuration. Why not use IOptions right after that line instead of creating the new instance? Like so:

```
 services.AddScoped<IDynamicsConnector, DynamicsConnector>();

 services.AddScoped(resolver =>
 {
      var dc = resolver.GetService<IDynamicsConnector>();
      dc.DynamicsConnectorOptions = resolver.GetService<IOptions<DynamicsConnectorOptions>>().Value;

      return dc;

 });
```

Then you can inject via a constructor like:

```
  private IDynamicsConnector _dc;

  public MyService(IDynamicsConnector dc)
  {
      _dc = dc;
  }
```