# Injecting settings into service from appsettings.JSON

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a service which read the data from a queue (Rabbit MQ - ProduceQueue), takes action  on the message and publishes the status on a separate status queue (Rabbit MQ - StatusQueue).
The issue I am facing is I am not able to instantiate the Producer and Consumer with separate settings when I resolve the service instance.

```
JSON Settings:
"RabbitMQConnection": {
"UserName": "guest",
"Password": "guest",
"HostName": "localhost",
"QueueName": "TaskExecutorPublisher",
"ExchangeName": "TaskProducerExchange",
"Port": "9090"
},
"RabbitMQStatusConnection": {
"UserName": "guest",
"Password": "guest",
"HostName": "localhost",
"QueueName": "SequenceStatusPublisher",
"ExchangeName": "StatusExchange",
"Port": "9091"
}

Program.cs:
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.ConfigureAppConfiguration(app => { app.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()); app.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json"); })
.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
{
    //services.AddMvcCore();
    //services.AddMvc();


    services.AddLogging();
    
    services.AddSingleton<IMQConsumer, RabbitMQConsumer>()
    .AddOptions<IMQConnectionConfiguration>().Configure(options =>
    {
        options.HostName = context.Configuration["RabbitMQConnection:HostName"];
        options.Port = Convert.ToInt32( context.Configuration["RabbitMQConnection:Port"]);
        options.UserName = context.Configuration["RabbitMQConnection:UserName"];
        options.Password = context.Configuration["RabbitMQConnection:Password"];
        options.ExtensionProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
               { "QueueName", context.Configuration["RabbitMQConnection:QueueName"] },
               { "ExchangeName",context. Configuration["RabbitMQConnection:ExchangeName"] }};

    });

    services.AddSingleton<IMQProducer, RabbitMQProducer>()
  .AddOptions<IMQConnectionConfiguration>().Configure(options =>
  {
      options.HostName = context.Configuration["RabbitMQStatusConnection:HostName"];
      options.Port = Convert.ToInt32(context.Configuration["RabbitMQStatusConnection:Port"]);
      options.UserName = context.Configuration["RabbitMQStatusConnection:UserName"];
      options.Password = context.Configuration["RabbitMQStatusConnection:Password"];
      options.ExtensionProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
               { "QueueName", context.Configuration["RabbitMQStatusConnection:QueueName"] },
               { "ExchangeName",context. Configuration["RabbitMQStatusConnection:ExchangeName"] }};

  });

    services.AddHostedService<ExecutorServiceAPI>();

    services.AddSingleton<IMQConnectionConfiguration, ConnectionConfiguration>(option =>
    {
        var connectionConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration();
        connectionConfig.HostName = context.Configuration["RabbitMQConnection:HostName"];
        connectionConfig.Port = Convert.ToInt32(context.Configuration["RabbitMQConnection:Port"]);
        connectionConfig.UserName = context.Configuration["RabbitMQConnection:UserName"];
        connectionConfig.Password = context.Configuration["RabbitMQConnection:Password"];
        connectionConfig.ExtensionProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
               { "QueueName", context.Configuration["RabbitMQConnection:QueueName"] },
               { "ExchangeName",context. Configuration["RabbitMQConnection:ExchangeName"] }};

        return connectionConfig;
    });

}).UseWindowsService()


ExecutorService code :
public class ExecutorServiceAPI : IHostedService
{
private readonly ILogger _logger;
private IMQConsumer _consumerConnection;
private IMQProducer _producerConnection;

public ExecutorServiceAPI(ILogger<ExecutorServiceAPI> logger, IMQConsumer consumerConnection, IMQProducer producerConnection)
{
 if (consumerConnection == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(consumerConnection));

        _logger = logger;
        _consumerConnection = consumerConnection;
        _producerConnection = producerConnection;
}
}
```

Comment: You probably looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57895096/what-is-best-way-to-inject-configured-options-instance-into-a-scoped-service). But below demo is a way too, you can refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

In appsettings.json:

```
"Settings": {
    "RabbitMQConnection": {
      "UserName": "guest",
      "Password": "guest",
      "HostName": "localhost",
      "QueueName": "TaskExecutorPublisher",
      "ExchangeName": "TaskProducerExchange",
      "Port": "9090"
    },
    "RabbitMQStatusConnection": {
      "UserName": "guest",
      "Password": "guest",
      "HostName": "localhost",
      "QueueName": "SequenceStatusPublisher",
      "ExchangeName": "StatusExchange",
      "Port": "9091"
    }
  }
```

Settings:

```
public class Settings
    {
        public SettingProperties RabbitMQConnection { get; set; }
        public SettingProperties RabbitMQStatusConnection { get; set; }
        
    }
```

SettingProperties:

```
 public class SettingProperties
    {
       public  string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string HostName { get; set; } 
        public string QueueName { get; set; }    
        public string ExchangeName { get; set; }
        public string Port { get; set; }
        
    }
```

In Progarm.cs  (.net 6) , add below code:

```
builder.Services.Configure<Settings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Settings"));
```

Then in HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly Settings _MysettingsM;
        public HomeController(IOptions<Settings> APPsettings)
        {
            _MysettingsM = APPsettings.Value;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var R1= _MysettingsM.RabbitMQConnection;
            var R2 = _MysettingsM.RabbitMQStatusConnection;
            return View();
        }
}
```

result:

[image]